# Error while installing BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

My question here is two fold. I am trying to install BeautifulSoup, but facing the below error:

```
Rahul-MacBook-Air:~ rahul$ sudo easy_install pip
Password:
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 8.1.2
Processing pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
pip 8.1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip

Rahul-MacBook-Air:~ rahul$ pip install beautifulsoup4
Collecting beautifulsoup4
  Using cached beautifulsoup4-4.5.1-py2-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: beautifulsoup4
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 742, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 831, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1032, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 346, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.5.1.dist-info'
```

Can somebody please tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

My next question is related to the previous one. I have installed Python 3.5.2

```
>>> print(sys.version)
3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
>>>
```

However on the terminal it shows me a different version:

```
Rahul-MacBook-Air:~ rahul$ python -V
Python 2.7.10
```

So when I try to install BeautifulSoup it starts pointing to Python 2.7 which I think is wrong. It should point to the latest Python version i.e. 3.5.2

Also I have Python 2.7 pre-installed at `/usr/bin/python` and Python 3.5.2 is installed at `/usr/local/bin/python`.
How do I default the Python version such that every time I open my terminal it is already pointing to Python 3.5.2

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: `Permission denied`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have trouble installing BeautifulSoup because the user you're running he commands under doesn't have enough  permissions to access a system directory. Try running  the command with `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Next, you're saying that you've installed Python 3.5.2, but aren't showing the command you're using to run it. I'm pretty sure it's something like `python3` (in any case, *not* simply `python`), so what makes you wonder why `python -V` shows a different version number? The command `python` runs a different Python interpreter.

If you want to install anything for Python 3.5, you'll need `pip3`, not `pip`.

You can make `python` an alias (or a symbolic link) to `python3.5` and probably rename the Python 2.7 interpreter to something like `python2.7`, if it hasn't been done already.

Comment: I am actually new to python and trying to learn things here. As per your suggestion I executed the command `sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4` and I could successfully install it `Successfully installed beautifulsoup4-4.5.1`
However on to my next question, how do I default the python version to 3.5.2
I did try to follow your answer, but if you could elaborate the answer, it would be much useful.

Comment: @RahulDevMishra, what do you mean by 'How do I default the Python version...'? Do you want the `python` command to open Python 3.5 instead of 2.7? I reckon `pip` would continue installing modules for Python 2.7 only, regardless of what the `python` command does. Also, the `python` file may be a fully-featured Python interpreter (not a symlink), and if you'll overwrite it with a symlink pointing to Python 3.5, this may ruin the Python 2.7 installation... To my mind, it's even better to have both `python3.5` and `python`, so you'd always know which command runs which Python version.